# Connecting to localdb from pyodbc

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc, sql-server-2016-localdb

Tried all sorts of variations to connect from python pyodbc to my local SQL Server

[image]

Also tried doing the \ escape

```
'Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;'
'UID=domain\\uname;'
```

but still get this error

I am able to connect to the same localdb from SSMS.

this is the error message screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you should choose between providing `uid/password` and `Trusted_Connection` I would suggest you to construct the connection string as follows:

```
"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=TestDB;UID=$user;PWD=$password"
```

Furthermore, if `localhost` does not solve your issue you can use `(local)` also and for a named instance `localhost\$instance_name`, you do not have to put 2 backslashes. Last I would strongly suggest you to upgrade your driver to the latest version. As you can easily set it in the connection string as follows:

```
"DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=TestDB;UID=$user;PWD=$password"
```

In addition you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to SQL Server Express Edition LocalDb requires an updated driver.  The legacy ODBC driver can't do it.  So either [get the new ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), or [download SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) (the Windows Service package).